# Hive check elements in array

Tags: arrays, select, filter, hive

I have an Hive table made of user_id and item_id (id of items that have been purchased by the user).
I want to get a list of all the users who purchased item 1 but not item 2 and 3.

To do this I wrote the simple query:

```
SELECT user_id, collect_set(item_id) itemslist FROM mytable
WHERE item_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING -- what should I put here???
```

As you can see, I don't know how to check whether the array itemslist contains 1 and not 2.

How do you do this?
If there is some more efficient way can you please tell me both (or more) methods?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are some collection functions in Hive  `(See [collection functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions) here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF ) which can use here.

You can use the `array_contains(Array<T>, value)` function to check if item 1 is present and  the `size(Array<T>)` function to make sure the length is 1. If both conditions are satisfied, you will get the desired output.

Comment: what if I wanted to display the item found in the select statement, how would I go about that?

Comment: array_contains is not working with regex pattern. For instance, if I want to check there is any item in array that have substring foo.*. Do you have any suggestion?