# Filter Array in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

An Apache hive table has the following column definition:

```
myvars:array<struct<index:bigint,value:string>>
```

An example for the corresponding data is:

```
"myvars":[
  {"index":2,"value":"value1"}
  , {"index":1,"value":"value2"}
  , {"index":2,"value":"value3"}
]
```

How can this array be filtered to all elements where "index"==2.

In JavaScript I would do something like the following:

```
myvars.filter(function(d){return d.index==2;})
```

How can the same result be achieved with Apache Hive QL, preferably without lateral views?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774332/hive-check-elements-in-array

Comment: i have this question too can you find any solution for it? let me know please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280628/how-to-filter-on-map-value-in-hive-arraymapstring-string

Comment: First link is not a duplicate, since this is a nested struct, not a flat array.  Second link's page seems to be broken...

Answer (score 2):

In **hive** you have a set of **Collection** functions:

```
 Collection
    array_contains(Array<T> a, val)
    array<K.V> map_keys(Map<K.V> a)
    array<K.V> map_values(Map<K.V> a)
    size(Map<K.V>|Array<T> a)
    sort_array(Array<T> a)
```

in your query use

```
...
WHERE
array_contains(myvars,2)
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are trying to extract all the values where index is 2, you want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM mytable 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(myvars) exploded_myvars AS idx, value
WHERE idx = 2;
```

If instead the data type was `array<map<string,string>>` it would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT mv["value"]
FROM mytable 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(myvars) exploded_myvars AS mv
WHERE mv["index"] = 2;
```