# Query a hive table with array<array<string>> type

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table and had to put a filter where the value of the column =[]. The type of the column in `array<array<string>>`. I tried to use `array_contains` but gave the following error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10016]: line 2:41 Argument type mismatch ''[]'': "array"
>   expected at function ARRAY_CONTAINS, but "string" is found

The sample values of the column could be

```
[]
[['a','b', 'c']]
[['a'],['b'], ['c']]
[]
```

Comment: Can you share the schema created using Hive and the query which you are executing?

Comment: @HRoy Query is this one.
`select * from table where array_contains(colname,'[]') = TRUE limit 50`
How do i share the schema. I am like not an expert in hive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774332/hive-check-elements-in-array
This had the solution to the problem. We could use `size(Array<T>)` function for this problem.